# Need some help with #define

Tags: c, windows

In the #define what does the L mean ?

```
#define NT_DEVICE_NAME      L"\\Device\\SIOCTL"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That the [string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69ze775t%28VS.80%29.aspx) should be of type wchar_t[].

Comment: L means string is of type wchar ?

Answer (score 0):

It means that the string is a unicode (UTF-16) encoded string. A UTF-16 string is a sequence of 16 bit words, rather than 8 bit characters. Windows's native format for strings is UTF-16. See here for more information about unicode: http://www.unicode.org/